# VB.NET Add row data to public class / public field of type List(Of T) Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: vb.net, class, public, generic-list

I am trying to add rows to a public class that has public fields and am getting an error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

```
    Public Class EmailRecipient
        EmailAddress As String = ""
        FullName As String = ""
    End Class

    Public Class EmailDetails
        Public FromEmail As String = ""
        Public ToEmails As List(Of Emails) = nothing  
    End Class

    Public Sub SetEmailDetails
        'Populate EmailRecipient Class
        Dim er As New EmailRecipient
        er.EmailAddress = "rodney@norespect.com"
        er.FullName = "Rodney Dangerfield"

        'Populate EmailDetails Class
         Dim ed As New EmailDetails
         ed.FromEmail = "sender@danger.com"   'This works fine
         ed.ToEmails.Add(er)                  'Here error happens
    End Sub
```

I'm guessing I need to create an instance of the EmailRecipient class before I can add an item to it.

Not sure how to do that with a Public Field in a Public Class??

It's been a rough day. I got up this morning, put a shirt on and a button fell off. I picked up my briefcase and the handle came off. I'm afraid to go to the bathroom.

Thanks for the help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm guessing I need to create an instance of the EmailRecipient class

You already have an instance of the EmailRecipient class. That's your er variable. You actually have two errors here. First, you explicitly set ToEmails to Nothing:

> Public ToEmails As List(Of Emails) = nothing

This means that your ToEmails variable is a Null Reference. It doesn't have an actual object yet.

The second issue is that you shouldn't get that excpetion, because this shouldn't even compile. You define ToEmails as a List(Of Emails), but tried to add an object of type "EmailRecepient" to it. That should be a compiler error. If it's not, you need to turn Option Strict or Option Infer back on.

So what you really need is an instance of a the List(Of EmailRecipient) type. Fix the bad line of code like this:

```
Public ToEmails As New List(Of EmailRecipient)
```

Comment: Thanks - declaring the public variable list as new and not setting it to nothing solved the issue :-)